# Move to next control at end of string

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2016

I have a form with a control that has a mask. The mask accepts 10 numbers, I have them formatted as short text. I will not be doing any calculation on them. They are just a string of numbers. I want the control to change focus to another control when I enter that last character. Example: I enter 1111-10-1234, when I type 4, I want the focus to change to the next control. I tried to use Len to change focus but it always shows the length as 12 since I have 12 place holders. Any other suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use the *SelStart* property:

```
If Me!YourTextBox.SelStart = 12 Then
    ' Cursor has moved past the last position.
    Me!SomeOtherControl.SetFocus
End If
```

Comment: This seems like a nice quick solution. I tried it and I get an error. "Cannot update. Database or object is read-only."

Comment: Sorry, I must have done something else wrong that made my control read only. I went back and tried it again an it works great. Thank you.

Comment: I am fairly new on here. How do I mark this as answered?

Comment: It should be somewhere to the left of the answer - at the up/down triangles and the digit.

Answer (score 0):

You can recheck the length of a string with numbers only. Use the regular expression functional to get rid of non-number signs in the string:

```
Public Function f_NumberExtractor(ByVal str As String) As string
Dim objRegEx As Object

 if len(str) >1 then
Set objRegEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
objRegEx.Pattern = "\D"
objRegEx.Global = True

f_NumberExtractor= objRegEx.Replace(str, vbNullString) 

else

 f_NumberExtractor=vbnullstring

end if

End Function
```

so, now u can have

```
len(f_NumberExtractor(me.cmbName.value))>11
```

check in your code.

Comment: I entered the code just as you have it except I changed the name of my control. I am getting and invalid use of Null error.

Comment: is it because of the nullstring case?